# Material UI - Swipeable Drawer - Allow drawer bleed interaction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `SwipeableDrawer` from Material UI trying to create a swipeable bottom sheet.  When the drawer is closed, the drawer bleed is set to 85px to create the effect that the drawer can never be closed.  When the drawer is "closed" or minimized, the user can see an input and am trying to make it so the user can interact with the component.  The problem is, the swipeable area is covering the component to capture and drag actions.  Is there any way to allow the drawer bleed component to allow user interaction and still keep the drag event so the user can drag the drawer open?

Drawer Code:

```js
const drawerBleeding = 85;

<SwipeableDrawer
    container={portal}
    className={classNames.join(' ')}
    anchor="bottom"
    id={id}
    open={isOpen}
    onClose={onClose ?? (() => void (0))}
    onOpen={onOpen}
    SwipeAreaProps={{ onClick: () => {}, style: {zIndex: 1100}, id: `${id}-swipe-area` }}
    swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
    disableSwipeToOpen={false}
    onTransitionEnd={onTransitionEnd}
    ModalProps={{ keepMounted: true }}>
    <StyledBox onClick={onOpen} sx={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -bleeding,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
        borderTopRightRadius: 8,
        visibility: 'visible',
        boxShadow: "0px -8px 8px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)",
        height: `${drawerBleeding}px`,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        pointerEvents: "auto"
    }}>
        <Puller />
        {headerComponent}
    </StyledBox>
    <div style={{ height: '100%', borderRadius: "inherit" }}>{children}</div>
</SwipeableDrawer>
```

Here is an image of the drawer:

[image: Drawer Closed]

The input, hamburger, and avatar all have the transparent swipeable area over the top and the user cannot interact with them.

I have tried to see if the drag event will propagate through to the drag area if I change the z-index of the drawer bleed component, but that does not seem to work.

Below is a where the drawer and swipe area are rendered on the page:

[image]

If I put the swipeable area behind the bleed component, I lose swiping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MUI@v5.11.6 there is now a `allowSwipeInChildren` field on the `SwipeableDrawer` component, simply set it to `true` and it should work like you expect it to be. There is also a possibility to pass a function. You can check the docs about it here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/swipeable-drawer/

I hope that helps :)